# Как заставить Ninject вернуть Mock-объект, созданный при помощи NSubstitute?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, mocking, nsubstitute, ninject

В моём проекте в качестве **IoC**-фреймворка используется **Ninject**. Для общего представления:

```
public class SomeClassFromDomainLayer
{
    //some code
    #region private properties
    private IContext Context
    {
        get 
        { 
            if(_context==null) 
            {
                _context = AppEnvironment.Kernel.Get<IContext>();
            } 
            return _context;
        }
    }
    #endregion
    //some code
}
```

Сам **NinjectModule**-класс выглядит следующим образом:

```
public class ContextNinjectModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Bind<IContext>().To<RealContext>();
    }
}
```

В настоящий момент я собственноручно создал mock-объект. Он отлично заменяет реальный контекст для юнит-тестов. Но неудобство состоит в том, что при любых изменениях в интерфейсе `IContext`, мне приходится изменять оба класса (классы реального контекста и фейкового). А хотелось бы использовать mock-фреймворк.

---

Вопрос состоит в том, можно ли написать такой, унаследованный от `NinjectModule` класс, который будет подставлять в поля типа `IContext` объект, созданный при помощи mock-фреймворка (например, *NSubstitute*)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-нибудь так пробовали? Каждая попытка резолва `IContext` будет отдавать новый стаб/мок-объект.

```
public class TestContextNinjectModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        // делегат в ToMethod принимает параметр типа IContext -- это тип NInject'а,
        // не путайте с вашим собственным интерфейсом!
        this.Bind<IContext>().ToMethod(c => Substitute.For<IContext>());
    }
}
```

В самом тесте вы уже сможете на него вешать ожидания и делать проверки (NSubstitute тут весьма кстати, поскольку это все у него реализовано методами расширения).

```
public void SomeTest
{
    var context = module.Get<IContext>();
    context.SomeMethod().Returns(42);

    var classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest(context);
    classUnderTest.Foo();

    context.Received().SomeMethod();
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понял, что значит "стаб", и что значит "вешать на него ожидания в тесте"? Не могли бы Вы привести пример тестового кода?

Comment: @klutch1991 обновил ответ. Стабы/моки -- это те объекты-загрушки, которые создаются с помощью мок-фреймворков. Ожидания -- это поведение, которое вы определяете для таких объектов, т.е. ожидаете, что будет вызван такой-то метод/свойство и он должен вернуть такое-то значение.